# WebStorm reports a "missing import" on built-in objects

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm

I've an ES6 project in WebStorm which obviously sometimes uses some built-in objects like `Math` or `JSON`.

Both *HTML / ECMAScript 5* and *ECMAScript 6* are enabled in "Settings/(...)/JavaScript/Libraries", yet WebStorm still suggests that `Math` and `JSON` are *missing imports*.

When I create an empty new project it works fine. I also noticed that when selecting `JSON` in such new project and pressing CTRL+B, WebStorm shows definitions from its internal library.

To the contrary in my main project it shows some TypeScript ones from completely unrelated part of the project. If I move the folder with typescript outside the project it seems to work.

Nota bene, the file I have errors in is not written in TypeScript, does not include anything TypeScript related and is not processed with TypeScript in any way. It is only processed with ES6 to ES5 transpiler.

Comment: Can't recreate. Please try invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, Restart) - does the problem persist? if yes, please try composing a sample project that shows up the issue. Note that you can suppress 'Missing import statement' inspection for these statement

Comment: @lena I got the same issue, clearing the cache and restart won't help. (i'm on pycharm)

Comment: It's been 5 month and there is still no answer or fix for this. It's pretty annoying.

Comment: @lena, is it possinle to at least find the file/direcotry which triggers the missing import behavior on the project?

Answer (score 46):

This worked for me:

- Navigate *Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM*
- Click *Enable* for *Node.js Core library* under *Coding Assistance* section
- Click *Apply*

I restarted WebStorm and warnings went away.

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger nope, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Using the current version I didn't even need to restart before this fixed it.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Apparently this problem has multiple potential causes.

Comment: Thanks - this fixed the squiggly underline for `process.env` variables.

Answer (score 4):

Marking the directory with TypeScript based subproject as excluded *(right click → “Mark Directory as” → “Excluded”)* solves the problem without need to physically remove it from the project.

Comment: Similar fix for me, I had to uncheck the `node_modules` folder in `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries` list.

Comment: The comment by @CodingIntrigue worked for me! Thanks

Comment: Rather than removing node_modules, which can have unintended consequences, consider simply checking the box next to `Node.js` to add the node library.  This worked for me.

Comment: The suggestion by @icfantv worked for me, but first I had to enable Node.js support in `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found the solution:
For me it was because I had a ECMA 5.1 project with a subfolder in ECMA 6.
Just invert it: Set all ECMA 5.1 files in ECMA 5.1 and set the main project version to ECMA 6.

Comment: how do you do this?